# Why is value not zero when I didn't initialize it?

Tags: c, printing, initialization, printf

Here's my code:

```
int main(){


        int age;
        int height = 72;
        // 
        double blab = (10/23242^4);


        printf("I am %d years old.\n",age);
        printf("I am %d inches tall.\n",height);

        return 0;
}
```

Having the `blab` variable makes the value of `age` is a random number. When I erased this variable, the value is zero, as I think the value of `age` was supposed to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, variables are allocated in one of two places: globally, or on the stack. By definition, global variables are initialised to `0` if there is no assignment; stack variables are not.

```
int willBeZero;

void Fn(void) {
    int uninit;
    int four = 4;
} // Fn(void)
```

So if a stack variable is not initialised, what value does it take? What ever happens to be on the stack at that memory location, which could be `0`.

If you want a particular value in a variable, you have to put it there.

Comment: They can also be allocated to registers, and in fact scalar variables typically are when any optimization is performed.

Answer (score 2):

Uninitialized local (non-static) variables have an *indeterminate* (and seemingly random) value. Using them without initialization leads to *undefined behavior*.